# Having a bit of trouble with post meta's

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I am trying to use post meta within WordPress to distinguish between real drafts and my own custom types of drafts, to do this I've set up a post meta called 'wpcc_is_draft_kw' that sets my own drafts to 0 and the standard WordPress drafts to 1.

The issue I'm having here is that when a page loads I'd like to grab just the real drafts that have the meta key attached along with the standard drafts that don't, avoiding the ones that I've set to 0 with the meta key for my own use.

This does not happen, and instead, all of the drafts seem to be coming through.

Here is the code that I'm using to do this:

```
<div id='external-events'>
    <?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'draft',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach ($posts_array as $wpcc_post)
{
    $timestamp = strtotime($wpcc_post->post_date);

    $keywpcc_value = get_post_meta( $wpcc_post->ID, 'wpcc_is_draft_kw', true );
    if ($keywpcc_value)
    {

        if (($keywpcc_value == 1) && ($keywpcc_value !== 0))
        {
        ?>
        <div id="wpcc_event_<?php echo $wpcc_post->ID; ?>" class='fc-event'><?php echo $wpcc_post->post_title; ?></div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <div id="wpcc_event_<?php echo $wpcc_post->ID; ?>" class='fc-event'><?php echo $wpcc_post->post_title; ?></div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a custom post status rather than using meta to accomplish this?

Comment: @NathanDawson yes, but that would require a lot of refactoring. So I'm looking for an easier route here.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found on the WordPress Stack Exchange:

Since the value I was storing for a not real draft was zero and I was making the comparison that looked to see if the value was set. I was not actually making the correct comparisons to determine whether or not something was set, just whether A value was set at all.

Here's a better explanation if you did not really follow that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109306/getting-wordpress-to-store-0-values-for-custom-post-type-meta.